# LogManager ignores enabled assertions

Tags: java, java.util.logging

While stepping through `java.util.logging.LogManager` code in a debugger I discovered that
due to exception at line 1301

```
try (final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(fname)) {
```

catch block at line 407

```
assert false : "Exception raised while reading logging configuration: " + ex;
```

should but do not throw `AssertionError`.

VM options: `-ea -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties`.

Comment: http://www.yegor256.com/2016/06/17/dont-use-java-assertions.html

Comment: LogManager has been restructured over the years.  What version of the source is this?

Comment: @jmehrens The latest one http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/logging/LogManager.java?revcount=120#l407

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `-esa` [enable assertions in all system classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BABDJJFI).  Per the documentation of `-ea[:[packagename]...|:classname]`:

> The -enableassertions (-ea) option applies to all class loaders and to system classes (which do not have a class loader). **There is one exception to this rule: if the option is provided with no arguments, then it does not apply to system classes.** This makes it easy to enable assertions in all classes except for system classes. The -enablesystemassertions option provides a separate switch to enable assertions in all system classes.

Here is a test case to verify the behavior which you should run with and without `-esa`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(LogManager.class.desiredAssertionStatus());
}
```

Another option would be to just enable assertions for user code and just the LogManager by setting the command line to: `-ea -ea:java.util.logging.LogManager`

Comment: What is the common sense behind dealing with not found configuration file like that?

Comment: @user2418306 Looks like an attempt to turn warnings into failures via a command line switch.  In some cases you might want the JVM to abort but in other cases it might be more important that main runs even if logging is crippled.

Comment: What are those *other cases*?

Comment: @user2418306  To be hyperbolic, autonomous vehicles.  Logging is just a subsystem and is usually not the end goal. Would you rather be stranded because logging is down or riding down the highway of life with your 'service vehicle soon' light on?  The answer depends on if you are the rider or the towing company.  Plenty of fine programs were written before and without logging frameworks.  If you want to make the case that the behavior should be different you can always [file a bug with Oracle.](http://bugs.java.com/)